# Does customized loss function impact backpropagation in Keras?

Tags: keras, backpropagation

I am doing one project by using Keras with tensorflow back-end. For business reason, I need to give high weight to some kind of errors, so I implement one customized loss function. For example:

```
error = np.abs(y_true - predict)
if error > low_limit:
    error = error * 10
```

I found that this customized loss function really changed the error value displayed during the training. What I am wondering is whether this new loss function really can change the behavior of backpropagation during the training? Because I did not see too much difference from the weights of my model.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, this loss function does change the behavior of BP, but I quite surprise that this loss function works...

Anyway, I feel the following loss function makes more sense

```
def my_mae( y_true, y_pred, low_bound=1e-3, coef=10. ) :
    raw_mae = keras.losses.mae( y_true, y_pred )
    mask = K.cast( raw_mae <= low_bound, dtype='float32' )
    #new_mae = mask * raw_mae * coef + (1-mask) * raw_mae
    new_mae = (1 + mask * (coef-1)) *raw_mae
    return new_mae
```

which gives extra loss when a sample loss is too low.